# Is it possible to intercept any call to a method of a class?

Tags: java, spring

In our project we're using `Spring Framework` and now I need to intercept any method call to any object method. Does `Spring` provide such a facility? I mean, for instance we have a method:

```
public void m(){
    MyClass a = new MyClass();
    a.method(); //I need to intercept that method call and invoke some stuff
}
```

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Not standalone Spring. You'll need integration with AspectJ.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Do yo mean that AspectJ is neccesary if I want to intercept any call to any method which probably is not a spring bean's method.

Comment: That's right. With Spring, you can only intercept Spring beans and only with some limited proxy aop behavior. You'll need AspectJ for fancy interception.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Just to clarify, Is `AspectJ` just a framework and can be simply applied via maven dependency or does it require integration on the `JVM` layer?

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that. See [here](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible - you'll need to use AOP. If you want to intercept every call of a method from **spring managed bean** then Spring AOP java proxying will be sufficient. Otherwise you'll need to use AspectJ.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include [Spring AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) in you project.

An option to intercept any call for methods defined in `MyClass` is:

```
@Around("* my.application.MyClass.*(..)")
public Object interceptAnyMethodCall(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

    Object retVal = pjp.proceed();

    // ... your code

    return retVal;
}
```